# how to fetch property from ef related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

with normal sql statement like below

```
select b.*, a.name from table_b b
left join table_a a on a.id = b.aid
```

in ef i build two related entity like below

```
public class A {
[key]
public int id {get;set;}
public string name {get;set;}
....
}
public class B{
[key]
public int id {get;set;}
public string name {get;set;}
[ForeignKey("a")]
public in aid {get;set;}
[NotMapped]
public string A_name{get{return this.a.name;}}
public virtual A a {get;set;}
...
}
```

my dbcontext code is here

```
mycontext.set<B>()
.Include(T => T.a)
.Where(.....).FirstOrDefault();
```

it works for me but look very foolish, as if class B has many related keys
as cid, did, eid, etc, one single record will take many data, so in ef
excepy sqlQuery is there any other simple way like noraml sql to fetch
extra property from other entity?
best regards! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can write a linq query:

```
var result= ( from a in mycontext.DBSetA_Name
              join b in mycontext.DBSetA_Name
              on a.id equals b.id
              into res
              from c in res.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new {a,c}
             )
             .Select(x=> new
                         {
                           IdA= x.a.id,
                           NameA=x.a.name,
                           NameB=x.c==null?null:x.c.name
                         }).ToList();
```

result will contain the exact resultset which your sql query will give.

Comment: thanks Sumit raj,  i once tried this mycontext.set<B>().Where(...) .select(T => new {T, A_Name = T.a.name}).FirstOrDefault(); it also works, but need another function to put A_Name into T, if B has many related ids it will be nightmare

Comment: It didn't work? I wrote this because only want specific properties not whole A.

Comment: before use ef, i use ado.net to fetch datatable then use entityconverter function convert to custome entity.  after meet ef and i'm a beginner with ef so i think the powerful ef can fit my request...